# Visual Studio debugger visualizers for Mozilla objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mozilla, debuggervisualizer

Are there any Visual Studio debugger visualizers for Mozilla objects (e.g. [`nsString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsString))?
I'm looking for something like the [boost visualizers](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/DebuggerVisualizers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tips in [Debugging Mozilla on Windows FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ) on it. Add the following entries to your `AUTOEXP.DAT` to improve Mozilla objects visualizing.

```
;; Mozilla (1.7beta and later)
nsAutoString=<mData,su>
nsString=<mData,su>
nsCString=<mData,s>
nsCAutoString=<mData,s>
nsRect=x=<x,d> y=<y,d> width=<width,d>; height=<height,d>
nsStaticAtomWrapper=<mStaticAtom->mString,s>
nsIAtom=<mString,su>
; the following are not necessary in vc8
nsCOMPtr<*>=<mRawPtr,x>
nsRefPtr=<mRawPtr,x>
nsAutoPtr=<mRawPtr,x>
```